# Firebase Storage: Object does not exist image upload path error

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I am getting an error every time I try to `add` and `image` to the firebase on the cloud.

```
FirebaseError: Firebase Storage: Object 'items/Screenshot at May 22 07-33-37.png9573dc82-ec43-4789-88ec-e93727d6a11f' does not exist. (storage/object-not-found)
```

The things is that the image it's being uploaded successfully on the storage but for whatever reason it can't be found and is not being added to the cloud.

What should I do?

This is my code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { db, storage } from './../../config/config';
import { ref, uploadBytes, getDownloadURL } from 'firebase/storage';
import { getDocs, collection, addDoc } from 'firebase/firestore';
import { ItemsList, AddForm } from './shopStyle';
import { v4 } from 'uuid';

export const Shop = () => {
const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
const itemsRef = collection(db, "items");

 // New item states
const [newItemName, setNewItemName] = useState("");
const [newItemPrice, setNewItemPrice] = useState(0);
const [newItemImage, setNewItemImage] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
    try {
    const data = await getDocs(itemsRef);
    const filteredData = data.docs.map((doc) => ({
      ...doc.data(),
      id: doc.id,
    }));
    setItems(filteredData);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
};
fetchData();
 }, []);

  function handleImage(e) {
e.preventDefault();
let pickedFile;
if (e.target.files && e.target.files.length > 0) {
  pickedFile = e.target.files[0];
  setNewItemImage(pickedFile);
  console.log(pickedFile);
}
}

 const addItems = async (e) => {
e.preventDefault(); // Prevent form submission

if (newItemImage == null) return;

const imageRef = ref(storage, `gs://cart-app-b469e.appspot.com/items/${newItemImage.name + v4()}`);
uploadBytes(imageRef, newItemImage).then(() => {
  alert("Image uploaded");
}).catch((error) => {
  console.log(error);
});

try {
  const downloadURL = await getDownloadURL(imageRef);

  const newItem = {
    Image: downloadURL,
    Name: newItemName,
    Price: newItemPrice,
  };

  await addDoc(itemsRef, newItem);

  // Clear input fields after successful addition
  setNewItemImage("");
  setNewItemName("");
  setNewItemPrice(0);
} catch (err) {
  console.log(err);
}
};  

  return (
<div>
  <AddForm onSubmit={addItems}>
    <input
      accept="image/*"
      id="icon-button-file"
      type="file"
      onChange={handleImage}
    />
    <input
      type="text"
      placeholder="name"
      value={newItemName}
      onChange={(e) => setNewItemName(e.target.value)}
    />
    <input
      type="number"
      placeholder="price"
      value={newItemPrice}
      onChange={(e) => setNewItemPrice(e.target.value)}
    />
    <button onClick={addItems}>Add</button>
  </AddForm>
  <ItemsList>
    {items.map((item) => (
      <div key={item.id}>
        <img src={item.Image} alt={item.Name} />
        <h1>{item.Name}</h1>
        <h4>{item.Price}</h4>
      </div>
    ))}
  </ItemsList>
</div>
);
};
```

I can't seem to see how to get the path right....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the way you are defining the ref for firebase storage objects. In your code, you're using a `gs:// URL` format, which is not recommended  using the Firebase SDK. You can directly reference the image using its path within the storage bucket.

You need to change the following line :

```
const imageRef = ref(storage, `gs://cart-app-b469e.appspot.com/items/${newItemImage.name + v4()}`);
```

To

```
const imageRef = ref(storage, `items/${newItemImage.name + v4()}`);
```

Which will store the uploaded object to the `items` folder with `${newItemImage.name + v4()}` as a file name.

As you are immediately getting the downloadURL with :

```
const downloadURL = await getDownloadURL(imageRef);
```

But this code will have the possibility to run before the upload file code so it is better to wait for the upload to complete using async await as follows :

```
const addItems = async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault(); 
  if (newItemImage == null) return;
  const imageRef = ref(storage, `items/${newItemImage.name + v4()}`);
  try {
    await uploadBytes(imageRef, newItemImage);
    alert("Image uploaded");
    const downloadURL = await getDownloadURL(imageRef);
    const newItem = {
      Image: downloadURL,
      Name: newItemName,
      Price: newItemPrice,
    };
    await addDoc(itemsRef, newItem);
    setNewItemImage("");
    setNewItemName("");
    setNewItemPrice(0);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};
```

May be after following above code downloadURL will be retrieved and stored in the Firestore document without any errors.

Reference : [**Upload from a Blob or File**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files#upload_from_a_blob_or_file)

Answer (score 0):

```
These changes in state, combined with the properties of the TaskSnapshot provide a simple yet powerful way to monitor upload events.

import { getStorage, ref, uploadBytesResumable, getDownloadURL } from "firebase/storage";

const storage = getStorage();
const storageRef = ref(storage, 'images/rivers.jpg');

const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, file);

// Register three observers:
// 1. 'state_changed' observer, called any time the state changes
// 2. Error observer, called on failure
// 3. Completion observer, called on successful completion
uploadTask.on('state_changed', 
  (snapshot) => {
    // Observe state change events such as progress, pause, and resume
    // Get task progress, including the number of bytes uploaded and the total number of bytes to be uploaded
    const progress = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
    console.log('Upload is ' + progress + '% done');
    switch (snapshot.state) {
      case 'paused':
        console.log('Upload is paused');
        break;
      case 'running':
        console.log('Upload is running');
        break;
    }
  }, 
  (error) => {
    // Handle unsuccessful uploads
  }, 
  () => {
    // Handle successful uploads on complete
    // For instance, get the download URL: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/...
    getDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref).then((downloadURL) => {
      console.log('File available at', downloadURL);
    });
  }
);
```